# Custom Activities Creation in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was reading info on this: https://code.exacttarget.com/marketing-automation/journey-builder/interactions/activities/custom-activities and I'm wondering when will custom activities creation will be available in App Center?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Custom Triggers and Activities are enabled in your AppCenter account once you have purchased and installed Journey Builder.  If you're interested in finding out more about Journey Builder, here is where you start: http://www.exacttarget.com/products/marketing-automation/journey-builder

Comment: I have Journey Builder, should I reach out to support so they tie enable my user in AppCenter to have access to creating custom activities?

Comment: Please reach out to jbdev@exacttarget.com and we can get you in touch with the right people to get you started